# how to install the module cyruslib

Tags: python, cyrus

tell me, please, how to install cyruslib? I'm use python 2.7, ubuntu18. I have the error :"No module named cyruslib". I want to do [enter link description here](http://python-cyrus.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: you can't install it as a package, all you need to extract the download folder, and then add the inermost cryuslib.py and seivelib.py in same folder or file path where you are importing it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of links that might help
https://sourceforge.net/projects/python-cyrus/
https://github.com/cyrusimap/cyruslibs

Answer (score 0):

**Run through source code:**

Download the files from this link : https://sourceforge.net/projects/python-cyrus/files/

Then extract it.

Then copy the python files from the extracted folder to your folder where you are creating your program

Now you must be able to do `import cyruslib` without issues